# Where does Aphex Twin's "windowlicker" equation come from?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

$\Delta M_i^{-1} = -\alpha \sum\limits_{n=1}^N D_i [n] \left[\sum\limits_{j \in C[i]}  F_{ji} [n-1] + Fext_i [n^{-1}]\right]$

This is the name of the second song on Aphex Twin's album "Windowlicker". It comes with no variable descriptions or other hints as to its origin. A spectrogram analysis of the song is available here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9xMuPWAZW8

Comment: This is not a research question. Please see the FAQ.

Comment: I think this question is better than many. The only problem that it might have no answer in principle...